# libcurl.so.4: no version information available

Tags: ubuntu, curl, libcurl

I have an user account on a server (Ubuntu 18.04, no root rights) and try to execute a program in which `libcurl` is dynamically linked but returns the error `../libcurl.so.4: no version information available`. Similar posts state that the error is caused by different installed versions. Since I had a different curl version installed in anaconda I did `conda remove curl`. I then have built and installed the latest curl version to my home directory.  However, `curl --version` now shows `-bash: /home/myuser/anaconda3/bin/curl: No such file or directory`, but I have installed the latest version to `~/programs/curl-libs/`. Moreover, `which curl` returns nothing. If I manually call the binary from there the output is as expected, i.e.,

```
myuser@hpc2:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myuser/programs/curl-libs/lib /home/myuser/programs/curl-libs/bin/curl --version
curl 7.71.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.71.1 zlib/1.2.11
Release-Date: 2020-07-01
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile libz UnixSockets
```

Is it possible that the error message described in the title is because the command `curl` points to the wrong binary? Do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a command it looks into current dir and directories mentioned in $PATH var. So you need to add /home/myuser/programs/curl-libs/bin/ to PATH env var.

export PATH="$PATH:home/myuser/programs/curl-libs/bin/"

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue that `curl --version` now shows the expected output. However, sadly executing my program still returns `../libcurl.so.4: no version information available`. Btw.: if it helps, I execute my program via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/myuser/programs/boost-libs/lib:/home/myuser/programs/curl-libs/lib" ./myrun.sh`

Comment: There is definitely two version of libcurl.so present on your system. Try finding them and removing one.